# Paypal IPN listener page inserting MySQL data multiple times

Tags: mysql, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I have been experimenting all day with the PayPal IPN listener in sandbox mode, trying to adapt the sample code for my own use. I am confused with the results I am getting - the MySQL query to be run at the bottom if inserting 6 lines of data for each IPN sent to the listener script. I've changed the query and have reproduced a typical insert to the database to illustrate my point - see the table below the code. Any ideas? I'm sure I remember this happening before with some other API but sure it will be something fundamental causing it. I will of course escape the data properly once I can verify that the form is working.

```
<?php
$dbc = mysqli_connect ('host', 'user', 'pass', 'db');

// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$req .= "&$key=$value";
}
// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

$fp = fsockopen ('www.sandbox.paypal.com', 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);


if (!$fp) {
// HTTP ERROR
} else {
fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
while (!feof($fp)) {
$res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
if ((stristr ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) &&
($_POST['payment_status'] == 'Completed'))
{

// PAYMENT VALIDATED & VERIFIED!
$email = $_POST['payer_email'];

$next = mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES('$email', NOW() ) ");  

$to      = $email;
$subject = 'Download Area | Login credentials';
$message = '

Thank you for your purchase

Your account information
-------------------------
Email: '.$email.'
Password: 
-------------------------

You can now login at http://yourwebsite.com/PayPal/';
$headers = 'From:noreply@downloadarea.com' . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

}
```

The data I got from one IPN is as follows:

```
+----+-------------------+---------------------+
| id | email             | password            |
+----+-------------------+---------------------+
| 25 | testing@gmail.com | 2013-07-03 17:15:58 |
+----+-------------------+---------------------+
| 26 | testing@gmail.com | 2013-07-03 17:15:58 |
+----+-------------------+---------------------+
| 27 | testing@gmail.com | 2013-07-03 17:15:58 |
+----+-------------------+---------------------+
| 28 | testing@gmail.com | 2013-07-03 17:15:58 |
+----+-------------------+---------------------+
| 29 | testing@gmail.com | 2013-07-03 17:15:59 |
+----+-------------------+---------------------+
| 30 | testing@gmail.com | 2013-07-03 17:15:59 |
+----+-------------------+---------------------+
```

Why is data being inserted multiple times for this IPN?

Answer (score 2):

If your script doesn't return a 200 OK response back to PayPal their system will continue POSTing the same data to your script until it does get one.  If your script runs successfully except for some small error at the end it could result in what you're seeing where the data was actually inserted correctly, but then PayPal keeps sending the notification so it keeps adding it again and again.

You need to make sure your script is returning 200 OK.  Check your IPN history in the sandbox account to see what it's showing there.

I like to test in a browser so I can see the result on screen and weed out any issues.  To do this, create a basic HTML form with hidden fields that match the fields you'd expect to get back from the IPN.  Set the action of the form to your IPN script and then you can load that and submit it in the browser so you can see the result on screen.  Once you have this working without failure and only inserting a single item into the database then you can rest assured it will work the same way from PayPal.

Just keep in mind when testing that way that the data will be unverified since it didn't actually come from PayPal, so you'll need to adjust your code (depending on how you're handling unverified IPN's) accordingly for testing purposes.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Angell I'll give it a try and report back on here

Comment: And even if you do return 200 you can sill get duplicates. You must check for duplicates yourself.